# Failed to send Extended APDU

Tags: javacard

I have a big byte array (it's `320` bytes) on my Java Card and I want to send its data in one APDU response.

So, I implemented `ExtendedLength` interface in my applet and then used the following program:

```
package exPack;

import javacard.framework.*;
import javacardx.apdu.ExtendedLength;

public class testExtended extends Applet implements ExtendedLength {

    byte[] longData = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09};

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        new testExtended();
    }

    protected testExtended() {
        register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) {
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x9001);
        }
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        short toSend = (short) longData.length;
        byte counter = 0;
        while (toSend > 0) {
            Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(longData, (short) (counter * 32), buffer, (short) 0, (short) 32);
            apdu.sendBytes((short) 0, (short) 32);
            toSend = (short) (toSend - 32);
            counter = (byte) (counter + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the line `apdu.sendBytes((short) 0, (short) 32);` I I receive a `0x6F00` error. I found the point of error using throwing an exception before and then after this line.

This is the response of above program:

```
Download Cap begin...
Download Cap successful.
Install Applet begin...
Install Applet successful.
Send: 00 A4 04 00 06 11 22 33 44 55 11 00
Recv: 90 01
Time used: 15.000 ms
Send: 00 00 00 00
Recv: 6F 00
Time used: 11.000 ms
```

Can anybody help me to handle it?

Comment: I think you should call `setOutgoing()` and `setOutgoingLength((short) 320);` before calling `sendBytes`. That is what I always do in my applets.

Comment: @vojta It returns a `0x6F00` exception in the line `setOutgoingLength((short) 320);`. I tried adding these to lines both inside and outside the while loop. When I replace `320` with `32`, I don't receive any error,  but it returns only first 32 bytes.

Comment: I did not notice you use `sendBytes`! You should use `sendBytesLong` instead! This way:

`apdu.sendBytesLong(longData, (short) (counter * 32), (short) 32);`

Comment: @vojta And no need to `arrayCopyNonAtomic()` method anymore?

Comment: @vojta I replaced `sendBytes` with `apdu.sendBytesLong`, but I still receive `0x6F00` (With and without `setOutgoing()` and `setOutgoingLength((short) 320);` methods outside the while loop).

Comment: What about Extended APDU Format? It is possible that your card receives standard APDU and that is why it does not allow extended responses...

Comment: Could you please try sending `00 00 00 00 00 00 00` instead of `00 00 00 00`? See http://askra.de/software/jcdocs/app-notes-2.2.2/extapdu.html

Comment: I tried the extended for APDU command (`00 00 00 00 00 00 00`) and still receiving same error.

Comment: Are your cards T=0, or T=1?

Comment: @vojta The card is working with `T=1`

Comment: Did the code from my answer work, or did you give it up? I am just curious.

Comment: @vojta No, I didn't give up. It worked fine for me! :) Thanks. I don't know what was wrong with my program, I followed the steps that you suggested me in the comment. Anyway it works fine, thank you again dear Vojta. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made your code work on all my cards:

```
import javacard.framework.*;
import javacardx.apdu.ExtendedLength;

public class MiniApplet extends Applet implements ExtendedLength {

    byte[] longData = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09};

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        new MiniApplet();
    }

    protected MiniApplet() {
        register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) {
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            return;
        }
        short toSend = (short) longData.length;

        try {
            apdu.setOutgoing();
            apdu.setOutgoingLength(toSend);

            byte counter = 0;
            while (toSend > 0) {
                apdu.sendBytesLong(longData, (short) (32 * counter), (short) 32);
                toSend = (short) (toSend - 32);
                counter = (byte) (counter + 1);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof APDUException) {
                APDUException ae = (APDUException) e;
                short reason = ae.getReason();
                if (reason == APDUException.BAD_LENGTH)
                    ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x9990);
                else
                    ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x8887);
            } else {
                ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x8888);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

APDU log:

```
=> 00 A4 04 00 08 F0 6D 69 6E 69 61 70 70 00  //different AID, not important
<= 90 00 //I got rid of your 9001, because it made my simulator mad

=> 00 00 00 00  //standard format                                       
<= 99 90 //APDUException.BAD_LENGTH thrown by apdu.setOutgoingLength(>256)

=> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 //extended APDU format
<= 00 10 ... all your data, 320 bytes ... 90 00
```

If this code does not work on your cards, it will be probably a bug in your `javacardx` package implementation and you should contact the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

An unhandled exception was thrown by your applet because you called `sendBytes()` without calling `setOutgoing()` and `setOutgoingLength()` first.

Also, I haven't really counted the length of `longData` but make sure that its length is a multiple of 32 bytes otherwise `Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic()` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and will make your applet throw `6F00`.

Maybe you can try it this way:

> ```
>     apdu.setOutgoing();
>     apdu.setOutgoingLength(toSend);
>     while (toSend > 0) {
>         Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(longData, (short) (counter * 32), buffer, (short) 0, (short) 32);
>         apdu.sendBytes((short) 0, (short) 32);
>         toSend = (short) (toSend - 32);
>         counter = (byte) (counter + 1);
>     }
> ```

Or much better, instead of doing a while loop:

> ```
>     apdu.setOutgoing();
>     apdu.setOutgoingLength(toSend);
>     apdu.sendBytesLong(longData, (short)0, toSend);
> ```

Comment: Mr @Vojta, had already suggested this modifications in the comments under the question and I tried both, but nothing changed and I still receive `0X6F00` for both. Thank you.

Comment: Can you update your question to show your updated code with calls to setOutgoing() and setOutgoingLength()?