# How to send bytes longer than 256 via response apdu

Tags: digital-signature, javacard, apdu

Look at the below code:

```
private void send_certificate (APDU apdu) {


if(!pin.isValidated())ISOException.throwIt(SW_PIN_VERIFICATION_REQUIRED);
else{


    apdu.setOutgoing();
    apdu.setOutgoingLength((short)certificate.length);
    apdu.sendBytesLong(certificate,(short)0,(short)certificate.length);
}

}
```

Certificate is a byte array inside the javacard applet and its length is greater than 256. How can I send this without getting `APDUException.BAD_LENGTH`?

Also, on sending this byte array, how can I retreive this byte array from the host application ?
I attempt the following from the host application:

```
CommandAPDU card_cert;
        ResponseAPDU resp4;
        card_cert =  new CommandAPDU(IDENTITY_CARD_CLA, SEND_CERTIFICATE, 0x00, 0x00);
        resp4 = c.transmit(card_cert);
        if(resp4.getSW()==0x9000) {
            byte [] response = resp4.getData();
            String certf= DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(response);
            System.out.println("CERTIFICATE:" + certf + "--"+response.length);
            System.out.println(" signature to be verivied: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(card_signature));
            CertificateFactory certFac = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(response);
            X509Certificate cert = ( X509Certificate ) certFac .generateCertificate( is ) ;
            Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
            signature.initVerify(cert.getPublicKey());

        signature.update(card_signature);
        if(card_signature !=null) {
            boolean ok =signature.verify(card_signature);
            if(ok==true)System.out.println("verification completed" ); 
    }
        }
```

of course nothing executes after the `if(resp4.getSW()==0x9000)`since the certificate is not sent successfully to the host application. How can this be achieved?

After making my applet class implement ExtendedLength, I did the following in my send_certificate() method:

```
    private void send_certificate (APDU apdu) {
    if(!pin.isValidated())ISOException.throwIt(SW_PIN_VERIFICATION_REQUIRED);
    else{ byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
          short LE = apdu.setOutgoing();
           short toSend = (short)certificate.length;
           short cert_offset =0;
           short len =240;           
           if (LE != toSend) {
              apdu.setOutgoingLength(toSend);
           } 
           while (toSend > 0) {                
               Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(certificate, cert_offset, apdu.getBuffer(), (short)0, len);
                       apdu.sendBytes((short) 0, len);
                       toSend -= len;
                       cert_offset += len;
          }
    }   
}
```

This does not work: Fails with response code 28416.

Comment: I have read here that I can use extended apdu: https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/prognotes/creating_an_applet_that_can_send_and_receive_extended_length_apdus.htm#JCPCL174. However,  the tutorial does not give a detailed explanation as to how the data is sent. I understand that my applet class has to implement ExtendedLength. That I have already done. So how will my send_certificate () function in the javacard applet change to allow me to send the certificate(my data with length >255). Also, how will my host retrieve this sent certificate once sent from the Javacard applet ?

Comment: You can easily split the requested data into multiple APDUs and pass offset as a parameter... It is easier than it seems.

Comment: I edited to add my attempted solution. I still have an error. I was trying to split the data

Comment: @Vojta, I found this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415519/failed-to-send-extended-apdu. It still does not solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that your Java Card implementation and reader both support extended length. It may be that the implementations have thrown up barriers that will disable the use of full size extended length: the implementations may (incorrectly) limit the size of the APDU's for instance.

The reader may require that the ATR indicates extended length. NFC chips are notorious of not implementing extended length correctly (and Android is notorious for not enabling the functionality if they do). This is probably not your problem as the status word seems to be generated by the card.

The code of Java Card has a mistake, it should always use `setOutgoingLength()`. It seems that your code already throws the exception when this method is called, so I expect that the size you're trying to send is not supported by the platform. Besides that, your initial code using `sendBytesLong` looks correct as well. Of course your Applet should implement the `ExtendedLength` tagging interface.

Note that `6F00` (your status code, always use hex for those, not decimals) may be generated *by any unhandled runtime exception* generated on the card. So make sure that your issue is not created elsewhere when you try to fix your problem.

Extended length is a mine-field unfortunately. We're now in 2018 and the smart card world still can't seem to send 32/64Ki -1 bytes or over. Time to replace ISO/IEC 7816-4 with something that makes sense I suppose.

Comment: and don't forgot to implement the `Applet` class with the `ExtendedLength` interface to actually make it happen.

Comment: Adjusted for future readers, but that was already present in the comments by the author under the question.

Comment: I just discovered that in this example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415519/failed-to-send-extended-apdu) the user sends out data of length 320 in blocks of length 32. I substitute this example with my code and it works! Does it mean the data being sent out must be sent in equal blocks(like 10 blocks of size 32 to transfer data of size 320)? And in that case, does extended lenghth support padding and how?

Comment: No, it probably just means that the implementation only allows you to buffer a certain amount of data before it being send. Maybe you can try and alternate the amount of data being send to find out the values. Note that the underlying data layer may have specific sizes as well; e.g. T=CL / ISO 14443 uses frames of a certain size to send data. ISO 7816-4 is build on top of that. Welcome to the mine field.

Comment: PS feel free to add your own answer if you've solved it by using a smaller size of the data to send at one time.